# String context in python

Tags: python, string

Is there any better way to use python in this case?
Get the adjacent strings of the last apparition of a dot in a string (*or any other character*)

Could be a way to get the size from the first calculation inside the next one?

```
my_str = 'any.string.with.many.points'

my_str.split('.')[len(my_str.split('.'))-2:len(my_str.split('.'))]
>>> ['many','points']
```

Comment: Don't name variables `str` It overrides a builtin type.

Comment: yeap, just for the question code, here is not like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can split twice from the right side and then just pick the last two:

```
source = 'any.string.with.many.points'
print(source.rsplit(".", 2)[-2:])  # ['many', 'points']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> my_str = 'any.string.with.many.points'

>>> my_str.split('.')[-2: ]

['many', 'points']
```

Answer (score -1):

First, avoid naming variables after named types like str.

Second, you could simply do something like this:

```
stri.split('.')[-2:]
```

Which would return ['many','points']